# Proprietary software pre-installed on the PocketC.H.I.P.?

Tags: software

After reading about the [PocketC.H.I.P.](https://getchip.com/pages/pocketchip), I assumed that it comes with FLOSS only, because:

- Their page advertises:

  > Open Source Hardware and Software mean you can do almost anything!
- [Their FAQ](https://docs.getchip.com/pocketchip.html#faq) says:

  > **Is PocketC.H.I.P. Open Source?** Yes, and you can get the hardware files at our [github repo](https://github.com/NextThingCo/PocketCHIP-PCB).

But I guess that these statements only apply to a subset of the product, as [PICO-8](http://www.pico-8.com/) (which is proprietary) is [pre-installed](https://docs.getchip.com/pocketchip.html#applications).

So is there anything else? Or does it become a fully free/libre/open system (software-wise) after [uninstalling PICO-8](https://opensource.com/article/17/2/pocketchip-or-pi)?

I’m not only worried about applications (PICO-8 would be in this category), but also about firmware/drivers (e.g., for the WiFi, the GPU, etc.).

---

Comment: (Related Meta discussion: [Is it on-topic to ask how free/libre/open a product really is?](https://opensource.meta.stackexchange.com/q/772/138))